# console.log into devTools into Electron app and renderer process

Tags: electron

**Why my console.log doesn't display into devTools in my very simple electron app ?**

- I console.log into js file loaded by renderer process electron.
- If I console.log into main process electron I can view the result into command line with no problem
- I can see that the js file is loaded by the renderer process into devTools > network part. But nothing console.log wrote into devTools > Console part.

**index.js** :

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let win

function createWindow () {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false
        }
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    console.log('main test')

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS'] = 'true';
```

**index.html file** :

```
<h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>

<script type="javascript" src="midi-test.js"></script>

<button type="button">TEST</button>
```

**midi-test.js file** :

```
var navigator = require('jzz')

console.log('test')

if (navigator.requestMIDIAccess){
    console.log('OK')
}
else{
    console.log('KO')
}
```

- I don't want to use electron-log npm package for writing console.log into OS file.
- I don't want to redirect console.log renderer process to main process command-line.

Lot of questions about this issue but nothing simple response find.

Answer (score 1):

In the `index.html` file, replace :

```
<script type="javascript" src="midi-test.js"></script>
```

With :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="midi-test.js"></script>
```

Or :

```
<script src="midi-test.js"></script>
```

In fact `javascript` only is wrong